# Changing frame size of UIImageView in navigation bar not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, swift4

I am not able to change the size of my image in the navigation bar for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
private func setupNavigationBarItems() {

    let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "radius_image"))
    titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

}
```

It's as if the `titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2)` line isn't even working.

Haven't found any recent solutions that would help.

Comment: have you tried `self.layoutIfNeeded()` after `navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView`?

Comment: Just from a quick glance at your code: Would using `.scaleAspectFill` work better?

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht I just added it after that and it didn't work . I added self.view.layoutIfNeeded() to be exact

Comment: @ZGski if I use that then it goes past the navigation bar. The weird thing is, I can't even change the size of the image even when I use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView comes on top of UINavigation Bar title view. In your case you are not changing frame of navigation bar title view.
Using a custom UIView & adding that instance on UINavigationBar item should solve your issue.

```
let titleView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2)) // Add your frames
let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "radius_image")) // Give your image name
titleImageView.frame = titleView.bounds
titleView.addSubview(titleImageView)
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: Been stuck on it for half n hour. Thanks so much! :)